# Can I use css3 or css to swap a icon on a button

Tags: html, css

Right now I have a button with a span in it, I would like to have the abilty when the button is clicked that the span's bg will change and stay changed.Is this possible ? And yes I know I can use javascript for this but I would like a pure css solution if possible

Comment: Whats wrong with using Javascript? There are almost no reasons I can think of that would prevent you from using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was a link (`<a>`) you could try using the `:visited` selector, but since buttons aren't links, there's no pure CSS that'll do this for you.

If you can style an `<a>` to look like your button, and then you could use the selector:

```
a.fakebutton span {
   background: ....
}

a.fakebutton:visited span {
   background: something else;
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in numerous modern browsers due to security concerns. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: awesome, y didnt i think of that

Comment: note this was going to utilized in a version of our site on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you wont be able to achieve this without client-side scripting.

Comment: Dang, I guess I will use me some javascript